# Count the number of decimals place in a np float 64

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to count the number of decimal places of a np element. I tried the following, so transform it to a string:

```
element = 2.923
element = "element"
element[::-1].find('.')
```

but it returns me -1 and I should have 3.
Any idea why?

Comment: You do understand that `2.923` is a rounded version of the internal binary representation, right? There are a number of possible algorithms to determine the "best" way to represent the number. Right now you are delegating that to the string conversion.

Comment: `element = "element"` assigns the string `element` to your variable. That string does not have a decimal point.

Comment: It looks like you need a basic Python tutorial before you continue. Try `element = str(element)` in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting 'element' to a string. Try this:

```
element = 2.923
element = str(element)
element[::-1].find('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to do it using your method would be

```
element = 2.923
element = str(element)
print(len(element.split('.')[1]))
```

in your second line, you're assigning a string "element" to the variable. Thats why find returns -1.